# Show that the equation $x^{2}ax=a^{-1}$ is solvable for $x$ in a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the equation $x^{2}ax=a^{-1}$ is solvable for $x$ in a group $G$ iff $a$ is the cube of some element in $G$.

This is a home in the coursework of my Abstract Algebra Class. I am unable to understand how come abstract algebra could be used to solved this. Provided the solution I provided rarely used any abstract algebra concept. Kindly correct my perception regarding the use and understanding of Abstract Algebra.

I need concepts and suggestions ( material) to improve the concept.

N.B. Today was my third day in the Abstract Algebra Class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm completing your solution, but your basic ideas are good. I don't know about the "best" answer here, but indeed Abstract Algebra is a lot about juggling with symbols. A better solution would only use less juggling, but would probably not be largely different)

If the equation has a solution $x$:

$x^2ax=a^{-1}$

Multiplying by $(ax^{-1})$ to the left and $(ax)$ to the right:

$(ax^{-1})x^{2}ax(ax)=(ax^{-1})a^{-1}(ax)=ax^{-1}x =a$

(note that we use the fact that the product operation is associative, and that $x$ has an inverse, so we use the most important axioms of groups)

This can be rewritten as $(ax)^3=a$, so $ax$ is a cubic root of $a$.

Conversedly, if $a$ has a cubic root $b$ ($a=b^3$). Let's take $x=a^{-1}b$ (inspired by the root which has been found previously).

Then $x=b^{-2}$.... and you can check that this solves the equation by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

as $x^{-2}ax= a^{-1}$
pre multiply by $x^{-1}$
we get $xax= x^{-1}. a^{-1}$
so $xax= (ax)^{-1}$
therefore $(xax).(ax)= e$
post multiply by a
we get (xa)(xa)(xa)= e.a
i.e  $(xa)^{3} = a$
thus a the cube of some element of G

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solved in the following way but it seems quite incorrect to me. Kindly check.

Let $b$ be the solution to the equation:

therefore, $b^{2}ab=a^{-1}$

multiplying a both sides we have,
$b^{2}a^{2}b=a^{-1}a=e(\text{identity element})$

now, $(ab)(ab)b=e$

multiplying both sides by $b^{-1}$ we have,

$(ab)^{2}=b^{-1}$

again, multiplying $ab$ both sides we have,

$(ab)^{3}=a$

Is this a correct way to prove ?

Comment: Note, that it a group it is not necessarily the case that the elements commute. If they do, the group is called "Abelian." Since it is unclear whether or not your group is abelian, you are not allowed to assume that the operation is commutative. Hence, you cannot say, in your first step, that $b^{2}ab$ times $a$ is $b^{2}a^{2}b$. It equals $b^{2}aba$.

Comment: Plus, you also need to show the other direction (if $a$ is  a cube, then the equation has a solution)

Comment: @tarulen: Why is it necessary to show the other way around. I mean is there any meaning to why it needs to be shown the other way around. Could you kindly explain my doubt ?

Comment: You need to prove an "iff"  (if and only if) statement, that is, an equivalence: if one side is true, then the other side is also true. This usually means two quite different proofs. You need to prove that all values of $a$ for which the equation has a solution are cubes, and that all other values of $a$ are not cubes (this second statement is the same as "all cubes solve the equation"). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if

Comment: For example, the following statements are true, but are "one-way" only: " $a\geq 0$ if $a$ is a square", and "$a=9$ only if $a$ is a square". In your question, the equation gives a very precise characterization of cubes: it describes all the cubes and only the cubes.